# Selecting children from a parent row with a very specific ruleset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, orm

I have a parent model that has more than 30,000 records which have at least 3-4 children each. I want to be able to display the children on a table with a very specific ruleset.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=128)    


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    state = models.CharField(
        _("State"), choices=(
            ('A', "Apple"),
            ('B', "Ball"),
            ('C', "Cat"),
            ('D', "Dog"),
        )
    )
```

Using the two models above, I have filtered out all Child objects who's `state is "A" or "B"`. The part of the requirements that I find hard to meet is, I might have a some `Bs` inbetween the `As` and `Cs`, for example, arranged in a row:

```
 [R]        [R]         [R]
Apple       Cat         Cat
```

If they're without B-states inbetween, I want to retrieve the `As` and `Cs` but I have a special case where I want to retrieve the Latest `B` before the next `C` instead of the `A` or `B` themselves.

```
            [R]                                 [R]                     [R]         [R]
Apple       Ball        Cat         Ball        Ball        Cat         Ball        Cat
```

In summary:

I want to always select the latest B before the next C, if there are Bs after the As or Cs or the end of the row is a B.

Is this at all possible with PostgreSQL? For lack of querying everything out and massaging the data with Python, because the table I'm displaying the records on is paginated.

Comment: If you are representing trees you may be interested into [MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [Treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @PauloScardine Actually went about using MPTT to always pick the object right before it as a parent if it was a Ball. This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PauloScardine had a good idea, went about using MPTT to always select the object before it as a Parent if it was a Ball. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. It certainly will help someone in the same boat.